# How to append (non duplicate) data to firebase db using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase realtime db .I am trying to insert following form data in to firebase db but it does not use the name2 variable from form, instead it just insert name2 into db? Furthermore, how I append data to this db instead of updating same data every time i submit the form ? I considered using push but i don't want to create unique id/key each time in insert data!

**Update:**  Now I am able to insert form name by using :

```
var playersRef = firebase.database().ref("players/"+ name2);
```

javascript:

```
function writeData5()
{

name2=document.getElementById("nameField2").value;

number2=document.getElementById("numberField2").value;

age2=document.getElementById("ageField2").value;



alert("name:"+name2+" number:"+number2+" age:"+age2);



var playersRef = firebase.database().ref("players/");

//playersRef.set ({john:{number:+number2,age: +age2}});

playersRef.set ({name2:{number:+number2,age: +age2}});



}
```

db structure I want to achive:
[image]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write

Comment: The name is your id, you need to change the ref from `players/` to `\`players/${name2}\``

Comment: Thanks Morphyish. I fixed the problem by using var playersRef = firebase.database().ref("players/"+ name2); .But now before insert how i can check if the name is not already in db before i make insert ?If the name already is there I want to alert user that name is already in db ?

Comment: You could make a simple read request and see if that returns anything. If it does you do your alert, if not you push the data directly.

Comment: i would appreciate if you show me how i can send read request to find out if name such as John exist in db or not ?

Comment: pretty much what is indicated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once), with the ref being `players/${name2}`. Then you check if snapshot.val() holds a value or not. If it does then it already exists in the database.

Comment: do you think this type of checking for duplicate is fast enough if i have lots of data ? firebase.database().ref('/players/' + name2).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

if('null' !=JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))
{
  alert("found")
}
elert
{
  alert("not found");
}

})

Comment: No, it will be pretty slow as you will need to make a LOT of network calls to firebase. If you have already stored every players client-side I would suggest checking against that and not a distant collection. Otherwise maybe try to fetch all players ids (names) at once and use that instead.